# Нужны ли дефисы?

Tags: пунктуация

...содержат специально отобранные beauty, brain, mood ингредиенты.

Behemothus, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

О каких знаках речь?!
Тут об орфографии (в узком смысле) впору думать...
Я бы написал через дефисы, но это если в "одиночном" случае эти вещи пишутся именно так.
"...содержат специально отобранные beauty-, brain-, mood-ингредиенты."

А вообще кончать надо с этой смесью французского с нижегородским. 
Я еще могу понять когда "по-англицки" пишется весь термин, которому нет подходящего перевода, но делать такие гибриды на пустом месте - как-то "не есть гуд".

Comment: Вообще ужас, что творят с русским языком! Сплошной мудингредиент...

Answer (score 0):

Тут, вообще-то , перечисление, следовательно ,нужны запятые.Вы верно поставили знаки препинания.А зачем тут дефисы?

Comment: Я видел случаи, когда пишут что-то вроде "Аудио- и видеозаписи". Здесь, видимо, похожая ситуация.